# MySQL SELECT IF statement

Tags: mysql, if-statement, left-join

I have 4 tables; loans (has 'user_id'), users (has 'student_ID' and 'teacher_ID'), student, and teacher.

The code I tried:

```
SELECT *FROM loans LEFT JOIN users ON loans.user_id=users.user_id
(
IF student_ID='1' THEN (SELECT *FROM teacher)
ELSE (SELECT *FROM student)
)
```

The code is not working properly. I want the `loans` display the `student` or `teacher` name from `users`. I have tried similia work, and it doesn't work either.

Comment: And the question is?

Comment: `IF student_ID='1'` technically, that's an assigment, rather than a comparison `IF student_ID=='1'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
select *
from loans l
left join users u on l.user_id = users.user_id
left join teacher t on u.teacher_id = t.teacher_id and u.student_id = 1
left join student s on u.student_id = s.student_id and u.student_id <> 1
```

**Explanation**

- Extract every record in loans
- Extract records in users where there's a match on user_id

  - Extract records from teacher matching on teacher_id if user's student_id is 1
  - Extract records from student matching on student_id if user's student_id is NOT 1

Comment: Thank you so much! It works. Other than it only display one for each. It's enough to relieve me.